# Contributions for Membership completed, but Membership remains as Pending

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, pending

A client has found that a number of memberships are still set to Pending even though the Payment is complete. Payments were made online. Membership is not in Override.

Client does have a multisite but this has been in place for a long time, and these issues are sporadic.

Here are some entries from db

https://gist.github.com/petednz/7151675e9b1d7715a163

Comment: Do you have audit logging enabled? It might give a clue as to what changes there were to the contribution to take it from Pending to completed and what other changes happened at the same time in the DB.

Comment: good point. they don't have 'log' but do of course have membership_log, but i need to go back to them and ensure which they have since manually corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue on my CiviCRM installation. This is related to contributions status name which changed after being translated (in French at least), which prevented CiviCRM from finding the right membership status (the `Completed` status was translated to `Complété` [which wasn’t correctly tested in this code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Member/Form/Membership.php#L1332)).

A bug was reported to the developers by Sunil Pawar ([CRM-20881](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20881)), and a patch that solves this issue [was submitted on GitHub](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10670).

This patch wasn’t included in the core repository yet, but in my case, the patch works fine.

Olivier;

Comment: Useful info. thx